# Force encoding used in XHR request

Tags: javascript, jquery, utf-8, xmlhttprequest, windows-1252

In a browser extension I'm developing, I'm doing an XHR request to load some data, using jQuery:

```
$.get(url).done(function(data, textStatus) {
    console.log(data);
})
```

The remotely-loaded data is a windows-1252 encoded CSV file served with Content-disposition:attachment and without mime-type/charset header (I don't have control on the backend, so I can't fix that).

How can I force the browser to decode the response as windows-1252 instead of utf-8 as it apparently currently does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hinted by my previous research and the first answers, I couldn't find a way to do what I wanted using jQuery.
I worked around the issue by using a vanilla XMLHttpRequest with responseType=blob, as explained in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", url, true);
oReq.responseType = "blob";
oReq.onload = function(e) {
    var blob = new Blob([oReq.response], { type : 'text\/csv' });
    account.data = blob;
}
oReq.onerror = function(e){
    ...
}
oReq.send();
```

Fortunately, I was already using a Blob to post the data back to the server so I'm actually saving a decoding/encoding step here...

Comment: For me this is a good aproach but unfortunatelly the Chrome does not allow me to change the "async" with "sync" so if the blob does not work try this instead of blob things:

oReq.overrideMimeType('text/xml; charset=iso-8859-1');

Answer (score 0):

If you set the correct encoding on the request doesn't jQuery use the same encoding for the response?

So something along the lines of:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "test.php",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=windows-1252",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is possible. The [doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) says that you can specify the charset, but the browser will always make the request as UTF-8 (per spec):

> contentType (default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;
>   charset=UTF-8')
>
> Type: String When sending data to the server, use this
>   content type. Default is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;
>   charset=UTF-8", which is fine for most cases. If you explicitly pass
>   in a content-type to $.ajax(), then it is always sent to the server
>   (even if no data is sent). The W3C XMLHttpRequest specification
>   dictates that the charset is always UTF-8; specifying another charset
>   will not force the browser to change the encoding.

So the code will be like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=windows-1252",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

if this doesn't work you should create a "proxy" which converts your file from windows-1252 to utf-8

Comment: Thanks Patrick. Unfortunately, as you anticipated, it doesn't work.
The proxy idea is not possible as such, because the request has to be made with the credentials of the user.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the followings also can be useful for somebody.

```
function getData(url) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', url, false);
  request.overrideMimeType('text/xml; charset=iso-8859-1');
  request.send(null);
  if (request.status === 200) {
    console.log(request.responseText);
  }
}
```